# converting PDF table to data.frame in R...table to data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, tostring, gsub, read.table

I'm working on creating an automated process to pull tables from a yearly PDF report.  Ideally, I'd be able to take each year's report, pull the data from the table within it, combine all years into a large data frame, and then analyze it.  Here is what I have so far (just focusing on one year of the report):

```
library(pdftools)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

download.file("https://higherlogicdownload.s3.amazonaws.com/NASBO/9d2d2db1-c943-4f1b-b750-0fca152d64c2/UploadedImages/SER%20Archive/State%20Expenditure%20Report%20(Fiscal%202014-2016)%20-%20S.pdf", "nasbo14_16.pdf", mode = "wb")

txt14_16 <- pdf_text("nasbo14_16.pdf")


 ## convert txt14_16 to data frame for analyzing
data <- toString(txt14_16[56])
data <- read.table(text = data, sep = "\n", as.is = TRUE)
data <- data[-c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 14, 20, 26, 34, 47, 52, 58, 65, 66, 67), ]
data <- gsub("[,]", "", data)
data <- gsub("[$]", "", data)
data <- gsub("\\s+", ",", gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "",data))
```

My problem is converting these raw table data into a dataframe that has each state for every row and their respective values for every column.  I'm sure the solution is simple, but I'm just a little bit new to R!  Any help?

EDIT:  All of these solutions have been terrific and have worked perfectly.  However, when I try a report from another year, I get some errors:

```
: '  0' does not exist in current working directory ('C:/Users/joshua_hanson/Documents').
```

After trying this code for the next report:

### convert txt09_11 to data frame for analyzing

```
download.file("https://higherlogicdownload.s3.amazonaws.com/NASBO/9d2d2db1-c943-4f1b-b750-0fca152d64c2/UploadedImages/SER%20Archive/2010%20State%20Expenditure%20Report.pdf", "nasbo09_11.pdf", mode = "wb")

txt09_11 <- pdf_text("nasbo09_11.pdf")

df <- txt09_11[54] %>%
read_lines() %>%    # separate lines
grep('^\\s{2}\\w', ., value = TRUE) %>%    # select lines with states, which start with space, space, letter
paste(collapse = '\n') %>%    # recombine
read_fwf(fwf_empty(.)) %>%    # read as fixed-width file
mutate_at(-1, parse_number) %>%    # make numbers numbers
mutate(X1 = sub('*', '', X1, fixed = TRUE))    # get rid of asterisks in state names
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`readr::read_fwf` has a `fwf_empty` utility that will guess column widths for you, which makes the job a lot simpler:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- txt14_16[56] %>% 
    read_lines() %>%    # separate lines
    grep('^\\s{2}\\w', ., value = TRUE) %>%    # select lines with states, which start with space, space, letter
    paste(collapse = '\n') %>%    # recombine
    read_fwf(fwf_empty(.)) %>%    # read as fixed-width file
    mutate_at(-1, parse_number) %>%    # make numbers numbers
    mutate(X1 = sub('*', '', X1, fixed = TRUE))    # get rid of asterisks in state names

df
#> # A tibble: 50 × 13
#>               X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9   X10
#>            <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    Connecticut  3779  2992     0  6771  3496  3483     0  6979  3612
#> 2          Maine   746  1767   267  2780   753  1510   270  2533   776
#> 3  Massachusetts  6359  5542   143 12044  6953  6771   174 13898  7411
#> 4  New Hampshire   491   660   175  1326   515   936   166  1617   523
#> 5   Rhode Island   998  1190    31  2219   998  1435    24  2457   953
#> 6        Vermont   282   797   332  1411   302   923   326  1551   337
#> 7       Delaware   662  1001     0  1663   668  1193    14  1875   689
#> 8       Maryland  2893  4807   860  8560  2896  5686  1061  9643  2812
#> 9     New Jersey  3961  6920  1043 11924  3831  8899  1053 13783  3955
#> 10      New York 10981 24237  4754 39972 11161 29393  5114 45668 11552
#> # ... with 40 more rows, and 3 more variables: X11 <dbl>, X12 <dbl>,
#> #   X13 <dbl>
```

Obviously column names still need to be added, but the data is fairly usable at this point.

Comment: This is a fantastic solution.  It's very convenient to not have to estimate the white space yourself.  Thank you!

Comment: Poppler is changing some of the numbers to octal-escaped control characters for some reason. You can take them out with `txt09_11[56] %>% gsub('[\013-\037]', '', .)`, but then you'll be missing data that's actually there, which isn't ideal. You'd also need to change the `grep` to the slightly more robust `grep('^\\s{1,2}[A-Z][a-z]+\\*?\\s', ., value = TRUE)`.

Comment: Ah, perhaps not all tables are able to be extracted perfectly!  That's quite alright.  I can automate all of the years except for one, which I will simply just copy and paste into an excel file and then import into the file.  

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: If it's Poppler and not just the file itself, you could try `tm::readPDF`, which constructs functions that can use GhostScript or other means of extracting the text. It's way more finicky, though; it may be easier to use the same utilities directly from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Your `gsub`s are a bit overly aggressive. You are doing fine through your `data[-c(1,...)]`, so I'll pick up from there, *replacing all of your calls to `gsub`*:

```
# sloppy fixed-width parsing
dat2 <- read.fwf(textConnection(data), c(35,15,20,20,12,10,15,10,10,10,10,15,99))
# clean up extra whitespace
dat3 <- as.data.frame(lapply(dat2, trimws), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(dat3)
#              V1     V2     V3  V4     V5     V6     V7  V8     V9    V10    V11 V12    V13
# 1  Connecticut* $3,779 $2,992  $0 $6,771 $3,496 $3,483  $0 $6,979 $3,612 $3,604  $0 $7,216
# 2        Maine*    746  1,767 267  2,780    753  1,510 270  2,533    776  1,605 274  2,655
# 3 Massachusetts  6,359  5,542 143 12,044  6,953  6,771 174 13,898  7,411  7,463 292 15,166
# 4 New Hampshire    491    660 175  1,326    515    936 166  1,617    523  1,197 238  1,958
# 5  Rhode Island    998  1,190  31  2,219    998  1,435  24  2,457    953  1,527  22  2,502
# 6      Vermont*    282    797 332  1,411    302    923 326  1,551    337    948 338  1,623
```

Caution: the widths I used (35,15,20,...) were hastily-derived, and though I think they work, admittedly I did not go row-by-row to verify that I did not chop something. *Please verify!*

Lastly, from here you likely want to remove `$` and `,` and integerize, that's fairly straight-forward:

```
dat3[-1] <- lapply(dat3[-1], function(a) as.integer(gsub("[^0-9]", "", a)))
head(dat3)
#              V1   V2   V3  V4    V5   V6   V7  V8    V9  V10  V11 V12   V13
# 1  Connecticut* 3779 2992   0  6771 3496 3483   0  6979 3612 3604   0  7216
# 2        Maine*  746 1767 267  2780  753 1510 270  2533  776 1605 274  2655
# 3 Massachusetts 6359 5542 143 12044 6953 6771 174 13898 7411 7463 292 15166
# 4 New Hampshire  491  660 175  1326  515  936 166  1617  523 1197 238  1958
# 5  Rhode Island  998 1190  31  2219  998 1435  24  2457  953 1527  22  2502
# 6      Vermont*  282  797 332  1411  302  923 326  1551  337  948 338  1623
```

I'm guessing the asterisks in the state names is meaningful. This can be captured easily with `grepl` and then removed:

```
dat3$ast <- grepl("\\*", dat3$V1)
dat3[[1]] <- gsub("\\*", "", dat3[[1]])
head(dat3)
#              V1   V2   V3  V4    V5   V6   V7  V8    V9  V10  V11 V12   V13   ast
# 1   Connecticut 3779 2992   0  6771 3496 3483   0  6979 3612 3604   0  7216  TRUE
# 2         Maine  746 1767 267  2780  753 1510 270  2533  776 1605 274  2655  TRUE
# 3 Massachusetts 6359 5542 143 12044 6953 6771 174 13898 7411 7463 292 15166 FALSE
# 4 New Hampshire  491  660 175  1326  515  936 166  1617  523 1197 238  1958 FALSE
# 5  Rhode Island  998 1190  31  2219  998 1435  24  2457  953 1527  22  2502 FALSE
# 6       Vermont  282  797 332  1411  302  923 326  1551  337  948 338  1623  TRUE
```

Comment: This is such an elegant solution!  My gsubs were certainly overly aggressive.  Thank you so much for the help!